# How to starting XAMP port for MySQL in Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, port

I am having problem starting XAMP port 3306 for MySQL.

I'm using Windows 10. I have uninstalled Skype from my system. The first software I installed was XAMP. The XAMP control panel version is 3.2.1. Apache starts fine but when I start MySQL it give me the following error:
**Error**: *MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.*

I'm the only user of the computer (with administrative privilege). When I try to change the port address in my.ini file it does not let me save the changes saying "*Access is denied*". (I have installed the windows 3 times already but the same problem every time)

I tried "netstat -b" to see what service is using this port it's not showing any service that is using 3306 port. I have tried "netstat -b -p TCP" my computer gives the following message:

"*The requested operation requires elevation.*"

I need to start MySQL. What do I do to run it?

Complete log:

Here is the complete log:

```
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
9:17:45 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
9:17:45 PM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
9:17:45 PM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
9:17:45 PM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
9:17:45 PM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
9:17:45 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
9:17:45 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
:17:45 PM  [Apache]     XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
9:17:45 PM  [Apache]    XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
9:17:45 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
9:18:03 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
9:18:09 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:18:11 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

It says windows 8, but I'm using Windows 10. Thanks

Comment: Show us a complete set of the mysql error log. Complete as in from a start request through the errors and the shutdown. Also check the windows Event Log, MYSQL writes errors there as well if it cannot write them to its error log

Comment: Oh and SKYPE can use port 80 and 443, which would only effect Apache and not MySQL

Comment: If you cannot edit the `my.ini` file it sounds like either windows is messed up or you have some AntiVirus that is getting in the way

Comment: Out of interest, where did you install XAMPP to

Comment: Edit your question and add it there! NOT THE COMPLETE LOG Just one occurance of START -> ERROR

Comment: Does this not shout at you **You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for most application stuff but whenever you do something with services there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think about running this application with administrator rights!**

Comment: Thanks. Now I look stupid. Thanks again. And thanks for shouting.

Comment: Its less destructive that the liberal use of Cricket Bat to Head